# How can chess AI determine if either of the players can claim draw?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax

I am experimenting on chess AI and currently trying to implement detection of possibility to claim a draw.

A player can claim a draw if:

1. There has been no capture or pawn move in the last fifty moves by each player.
2. The same board position has occurred three times.

So, the program must store the history of the previous positions to be able to verify these conditions. This is OK in the situation when a human player claims a draw. But the AI is evaluating millions of positions. So, on one hand it should be able to detect the possibility of such a claim by itself or by the adversary x moves ahead to be able to prevent it in a winning position or to try to enforce it in a losing position. On the other hand this verification can result in a huge loss in performance because of all the copies of history tables created during the deep search.

Is there a standard implementation/optimization of such a feature?

Note: If the answer is implementation-specific, my AI is based on a variation of  minimax with alpha-beta pruning.

Answer (score 1):

For item 1, the standard solution is to store a counter in the current state; the counter is reset to 0 each time there is a pawn move or capture, incremented by 1 each time there isn't, and checked at each move if it is greater than 50.

For item 2, some programs keep track and check at each move, but that costs time and space, as you noted. Thus, many programs only keep track of past moves and ignore the possibility of draw by three-fold repetition as they look ahead in the game tree. Another possibility is to keep track of any duplicate positions that have already occurred, and only check if a look-ahead position is the same as one of those.

Comment: Keeping track of duplicate positions crossed my mind, too. However, this doesn't take into account the case when both the second and the third repetition happen ahead in the game tree. Or is this situation logically worth ignoring? I cannot get my mind around it.

Comment: You are correct. Many chess programs ignore the possibility of draw by three-fold repetition during look-ahead. Since that possibility is _not_ logically worth ignoring, the best chess-playing programs _don't_ ignore the possibility. They may work by recording each future position as a string in some [standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation), then do string comparisons on each prior position, or else by some other mechanism that takes advantage of the internal representation of the position.

Comment: Note that there has to be some standard representation of each position stored in the game-playing program. First, at the very least the player has to respond to a claim of draw by three-fold repetition by the opponent, even if the player will never make that claim on its own. Second, if the program recognizes a repeat position, it can use the saved evaluation of that position instead of recomputing the evaluation. Good chess-playing programs store large amounts of data, and purge no-longer-needed data when the situation warrants (as when a piece is captured, or a pawn is moved).

Answer (score 1):

For item 1, I suggest a counter that is reset whenever a capture/pawn move occurs. (As mentioned before)

For item 2, I suggest an Array of Zobrist Hashes in your Board class, where you keep track of the already occured Positions. If such a position is found (current zobrist == [iterate through all variation zobrists)], you raise the corresponding counter by one.
If a counter reaches 3, its draw => return 0 as positions value.

This method will work pretty fast during runtime because you compare obly ~50 integers maximum. Im you already have tts/hashtables, it will be easy to implement, since you then already have the code for the zobrist codes.

[Edit]:
Btw, these aren't the only draw possibilities, see "stalemate".

Answer (score 0):

Chess programs keep track of identical positions anyway to avoid evaluation cost - e4e5, g4 is the same position as g4e5, e4 and therefore has the same value, avoiding completely the cost of evaluating the latter. All you do is keep track after how many moves the position arose, and if it is different by at least two moves you do some special case handling.

Comment: I already keep track of the past moves. If I understand correctly, what you propose implies keeping track of the future moves as the program keeps exploring the game tree as well. If this is the case, the question still remains: how to implement this effectively in a recursive method?

Comment: One method to implement it is by memoization in the move evaluation function.